# What is おばあちゃん子?

Tags: meaning

I attempted to find the meaning of

> おばあちゃん子

but it seems that it does not exist in the dictionary.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a child who grew up liking and spending lots of time with his/her grandma.

Even after that child has fully grown up, s/he is still often referred to as 「おばあちゃん子{こ}」.

Naturally, we also say 「おじいちゃん子」、「パパっ子」、「ママっ子」、「お兄{にい}ちゃんっ子」、「お姉{ねえ}ちゃんっ子」, etc. as well.

Nothing to do with blood family, but we also say [テレビっ子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%81%A3%E5%AD%90) to describe a kid/person who grew up watching a lot of TV.  There is 「ラジオっ子」 as well, but it is used less often than 
「テレビっ子」.

Comment: Thank you. If we want to make an interrogative, can we say `あなたはどんな子ですか。`?

Comment: No, that would mean a different thing.  That asks about the general characteristics of a person.  To have someone reply 「おばあちゃん子でした/です。」, the question we often ask is 「（子供の頃）誰に一番[懐]{なつ}いていましたか。」.  「懐く」 means "to become attached" and it is a good word to know.

Comment: And someone finally asked about that important verb recently. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73517/how-is-%e6%87%90%e3%81%8f-read-in-this-case/73519#73519