# How is 懐く read in this case?

Tags: grammar, readings, reading-comprehension

I came across this word in a manga page, on the top right speech bubble. I'm not sure whether this Kanji should be read as なつく or いだく. Moreover, neither of the readings make too much sense to me, should I interpret this phrase as "Aren't you getting too attached?" or something along these lines, since it's (apparently) in the passive form?

[image: manga page]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 「なつく」.

> 「あんたあんまり懐{なつ}かれてないんじゃないの？」

means:

> "You are not liked much by (someone), are you?"

「懐く」 here means "to take to (someone)".

「懐かれる」 is in the passive-voice form.